# Derivative of x power series of exponents

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find the derivative of an expression of the form

$$
y = x ^ { {(x+1)} ^ { {(x+2)} ^ {...} } }
$$
with respect to x. This expression has a base of x and a series of exponents that are formed by taking the previous exponent and adding 1 to it

Sorry I don't the exact term for this. There must be some easy trick to solve this. Maybe something to do with chain rule?

Comment: Is this an infinite power tower ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think this evaluates to a simple expression. I would happily like to be proven wrong, though, because the question seems interesting.

Comment: "of an expression of the form" is somewhat misleading in the light of the answer below, because the given power tower is either infinite or zero! I think you should provide the original expression, provided it is well-defined and takes real values everywhere. Maybe in a different question because there's already an answer.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer For $x=1$ , it is $1$.

Comment: @Peter You are correct, though the function is still too bad to differentiate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function bumps to $\infty$ for $x> 1$ and is not well-defined in $x<0$. So, let's focus on $0\le x\le 1$. Note that this function is not differentiable in $x\in\{0,1\}$ and for $x\in(0,1)$, the quantity $(1+x)^{(2+x)^\cdots}$ tends to $\infty$, leading to the fact that $x^{(x+1)^{(x+2)^\cdots}}$ converges to 0 for $x\in(0,1)$, so do its derivatives.